# sql to html alignment

Tags: php, html

I'm having a little issue with sql displaying html for some reason it's displaying the first entry input from the database into the 2nd entry on the actually page so for example there is 2 users in the database they have id1 and id 2 and there names well user 1's id would display into users 2 section on the page and same with user 1 here is an image below of the issue
[click here to view the image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/027f41833bd7448ba89e40333866672b.png)

the complete code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor";
$dbname = "a3wasteland";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT UID, BattlEyeGUID, Name, BankMoney FROM PlayerInfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='header'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>


<div id="elCmsPageWrap" data-pageid="2">

<div>
  <div class='ipsGrid ipsGrid_collapsePhone'>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col1'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col2'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='footer'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>


          <li class='ipsWidget ipsWidget_horizontal ipsBox' data-blockID='plugin_20_sodPhpWidget_paxe9xcu5' data-blockConfig="true" data-blockTitle="PHP Code" data-controller='core.front.widgets.block'>

<div class='ipsWidget_inner '>


    <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_light'>  
  <style>
  .specialType_center th {
    text-align: center; 
  }
  </style>
</style>
  <h2 class="ipsType_sectionTitle ipsType_reset cForumTitle ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone <center> ">Arma 3 Player Stats</h2></center>
    <table class="ipsTable ipsTable_responsive ipsTable_zebra ipsBox ipsType_center specialType_center ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone">
      <thead> 


   <tr>
      <th>BattlEyeGUID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>BankMoney</th>
      <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
/* Other code */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["UID"]?></span></td></tr>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BattlEyeGUID"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["Name"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BankMoney"]?></span></td>
<?php } 
} else { ?>
    <td colspan="5">0 results</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>

</div></li>

</ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :)

```
<tbody>

<?php
/* Other code */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<tr> <!-- tr -->

        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["UID"]?></span></td></tr>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BattlEyeGUID"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["Name"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BankMoney"]?></span></td>

</tr><!--/tr-->

<?php 
   }  
 } else {
?>
    <td colspan="5">0 results</td>

<?php } ?>

</tbody>
```

update :

```
    <table class="ipsTable ipsTable_responsive ipsTable_zebra ipsBox ipsType_center specialType_center ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone">
      <thead> 


   <tr>
      <th>UID</th>
      <th>BattlEyeGUID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>BankMoney</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    /* Other code */
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr> <!-- tr -->

            <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["UID"]?></span></td></tr>
            <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BattlEyeGUID"]?></span></td>
            <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["Name"]?></span></td>
            <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BankMoney"]?></span></td>

    </tr><!--/tr-->

    <?php 
       }  
     } else {
    ?>
        <td colspan="5">0 results</td>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work either thanks for trying anyways http://prntscr.com/c6j7go that broke it even more

Comment: I guess there is no one who can help with this strange bug?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after hours of researching this and testing i figured out of the issue instead of having the  at the end of the first entry i had to put it to the last and now it's all working http://prntscr.com/c7uoco